# Get value of SharePoint Taxonomy Field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

I have one taxonomy control in my form like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix4kd.png

The requirement is to get the value (Test|7d780b6d-7404-44fc-9614-9dcea4a42fcd) based on the DisplayName which is the FieldName here (MyTaxonomy).

I have tried to get the value using the below jQuery but no chance...

```
jQuery('div[class="ms-taxonomy.ms-taxonomy-height.ms-long"][title^="MyTaxonomy"]');

jQuery('.ms-taxonomy.ms-taxonomy-height.ms-long').find('MyTaxonomy');
```

---

With the following SPAN I can get the value using this one however the SPAN doesn't contain the DisplayName on it...

```
jQuery('.ms-taxonomy.ms-taxonomy-height.ms-long').val()

<SPAN><SPAN id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00><INPUT name=ctl00$m$g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14$ctl00$ctl05$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl01 class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01 type=hidden value=Test|7d780b6d-7404-44fc-9614-9dcea4a42fcd>
```

---

Please do help.

I have posted the DOM code below.

```
<TD class=ms-formbody vAlign=top>
<!-- FieldName="MyTaxonomy"
FieldInternalName="VersionGroup"
FieldType="SPFieldTaxonomyFieldType"-->
<SPAN><SPAN id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00><INPUT name=ctl00$m$g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14$ctl00$ctl05$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl01 class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01 type=hidden value=Test|7d780b6d-7404-44fc-9614-9dcea4a42fcd>
<DIV class="ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02 InputFieldId="ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl01" SspId="c8c11c5d-c1e6-4d9b-98f2-c1b3db293461" GroupId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" TermSetId="f5318c5e-30a6-4cb8-834d-7a558304ad88" AnchorId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsMulti="false" AllowFillIn="false" WidthCSS="ms-long" JavascriptOnValidation Lcid="1033" IsSpanTermSets="false" IsSpanTermStores="false" IsIgnoreFormatting="false" IsIncludeDeprecated="false" IsIncludeUnavailable="false" IsIncludeTermSetName="false" IsAddTerms="false" IsIncludePathData="false" IsUseCommaAsDelimiter="true" Disable="false" ExcludeKeyword="false" WebServiceUrl="http://zin506/sites/LenzeLFMF/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json" FieldName="MyTaxonomy" FieldId="b38cb204-7ed3-4a1f-9810-e41bef7e6263" DisplayPickerButton="true" MinimumHeight="15" IsPercentWidth="false" IsUnvalidated="false" AdjustingHeight="false">
<DIV class="ms-taxonomy-control-holder ms-long" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02controlHolder><IMG width=16 height=16 tabIndex=0 title="Browse for a valid choice" class=ms-taxonomy-browser-button alt="Browse for a valid choice" src="/_layouts/images/EMMCopyTerm.png">
<DIV title="MyTaxonomy" class=ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor style="HEIGHT: 18px; WIDTH: 362px" RteRedirect="ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion">
<DIV class="ms-rtestate-write ms-taxonomy-writeableregion" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion role=textbox aria-haspopup=true contentEditable=true aria-autocomplete=both aria-multiline=true DisableRibbonCommands="True" AllowMultiLines="false" RestrictPasteToText="True"><SPAN title="" class=valid-text>Test</SPAN></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV class="ms-taxonomy-suggestion-container ms-rtefocus-invalid ms-taxonomy-hidden" id=ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02suggestionsContainer unselectable="on" RteRedirect="ctl00_m_g_68795b6c_a6d2_4a5b_905c_3d35d5cf3a14_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02editableRegion">
<DIV class=ms-taxonomy-suggestion-holder unselectable="on" needsNewRequest="false" addCreateNewWhileTrimming="false" isSpanTermSets="false"></DIV><IMG width=15 height=15 class=ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer src="/_layouts/images/CornerGrip.gif" unselectable="on"></DIV></DIV></SPAN></SPAN>MyTaxonomy </TD>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
jQuery('.ms-formlabel nobr:contains"MyTaxonomy"').closest('tr').find('td.ms-formbody input:hidden').val();
```

Comment: It returns undefined :(

Comment: That's odd. Can you post whole tr row?

Answer (score 1):

You could use: `$("div[title='MyTaxonomy']").text()` if you are only requiring the field value

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetSectionForField(internalName) {

        var found = null;
        // Look into all td with the .ms-formbody class
        var abc = jQuery('.td.ms-formbody').val();
        jQuery("td.ms-formbody").each(function () {
            var html = jQuery(this).html().replace(/\n/g, '');
            //Check if it contains the keyword
            if (html.indexOf('FieldName="') < 0) return;
            var start = html.indexOf('FieldName="') + 'FieldName="'.length;
            html = html.substring(start);
            var stopp = html.indexOf('"');
            var nm = html.substring(0, stopp);
            // if is the internal name we are looking for
            if (nm == internalName) {
                var elements = jQuery(html);
                found = jQuery('.ms-taxonomy.ms-taxonomy-height.ms-long', elements).val();
                return found;
            }
        });

        return found;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('.ms-formlabel nobr:contains("Taxonomy field Display Name")').closest('tr').find('td.ms-formbody input:hidden').val();

gives value as below:

Taxonomy Value|089d95ce-d97c-4f46-8cc1-fdd44ce696f7

Now you can split by | and get the value